# What's the receiver in an rspec example?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller_ng/blob/aacfd8/spec/unit/controllers/runtime/apps_controller_spec.rb#L17 , for example, I want to determine how the "get" method is resolved. The quickest way I'm aware of would be to dump *receiver*.method(:get).source_location, but I don't know what the receiver is here.

Comment: Have you tried `self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly specify the receiver of any unqualified message you send, as it is implicitly `self`. So, in your case, `method(:get)` will tell you who/what implements the `get` method sent to `self`.